# Again "Stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests

I know that is exception is thrown when DOM tree has changed and solution for this is to find element again after refresh but...

I'm doing following operations:

```
    sessionsView.filterSession(sessionName);
    lockSession();
    approveSession();
    completeSession();
```

At the beginning of execution this code `completeButton` is disabled and looks like this:

`<button _ngcontent-mfo-c209="" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right" style="margin-right: 10px;" disabled="">Complete</button>`

Lock and approve operations are done by rest API services. After approve complete button becomes enabled so I'm looking for it after this refresh and then try to click it.

```
public void completeSession() {
    By completeButtonByXpath = By.xpath("*//button[text()='Complete']");
    WebElement completeButton = driver.findElement(completeButtonByXpath);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(completeButton));
    completeButton.click();
}
```

but I receive

`org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

when I click `completeButton`

I also tried with such wait
`wait.until(not(ExpectedConditions.attributeContains(completeButtonByXpath, "disabled", "")));` but it didn't help.

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are doing

```
driver.findElement(completeButtonByXpath);
```

then at this time selenium is looking for `*//button[text()='Complete']` xPath.

And probably at this time, it is not attached to `HTML-DOM` causing `staleness`.

**Solution:**

1. A very simple solution is to put hardcoded sleep like this:

   ```
   Thread.sleep(5000);
   ```

and now look for `WebElement completeButton = driver.findElement(completeButtonByXpath);`

2. Modify `completeSession` to Just have explicit waits.

   ```
   public void completeSession() {
    By completeButtonByXpath = By.xpath("*//button[text()='Complete']");
    //WebElement completeButton = driver.findElement(completeButtonByXpath);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(completeButtonByXpath)).click();
   }
   ```
3. Retry `clicking`.

**Code:**

```
public void completeSession() {
    By completeButtonByXpath = By.xpath("*//button[text()='Complete']");
    WebElement completeButton = driver.findElement(completeButtonByXpath);
    int attempts = 0;
    while(attempts < 5) {
        try {
            completeButton.click();
            break;
        }
        catch(StaleElementReferenceException staleException) {
            staleException.printStackTrace();
        }
        attempts++;
    }
}
```