# How to go through the pages and extract the link from them with Slenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm having problems capturing the link of the pages.

Below is the code, terminal output message and HTML image where the link is located.

[image]

```
classe = driver.find_elements(By. XPATH, "//*[@class='LinksShowcase_UrlContainer__kMj_n']/p")

for pages in range(2,6):
    driver.get("https://www.xxxx.com.br/painel/my-links?page="+ str(pages)+"&items=6&q=&startDate=&endDate=&popular=0")
    sleep(2)

    for i in classe:
        #pages += 1
        links.append(i.text)
        print(links)
        sleep(2)

terminal output message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Web\VS\Link Afiliado\teste.py", line 61, in <module>
    links.append(i.text)
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Web\Py\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 89, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)["value"]
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Web\Py\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 410, in _execute        
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Web\Py\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\felip\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Web\Py\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document        
  (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.125)
```

Comment: javascript technique can fix this, refer this for reason https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71881850/again-stale-element-reference-element-is-not-attached-to-the-page-document

Comment: Calling `driver.get()` loads a new page into the browser, and so the elements in `classe` become stale .

Comment: I tried without success wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(links.append(i.text)))

Comment: Can you post the correct URL?

Comment: try javascript within python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794087/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python

Comment: AbiSaran
 
it is a site where you need to register to access the URL that I need to extract

Comment: John Gordon
you solved my problem, in view of what you said I simply changed the position of FOR, I will leave my wrong code in the post but I will post a print in this comment so you can understand what was done.

https://prnt.sc/dkMHl3i9ee-4

https://prnt.sc/e63PuxVTu_tS

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment with reference of to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794087/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python) and also from my experience, any html element which rendered beyond the browser viewpoint which still going to appear based on user focus or scroll you can use `javascript` to get the element

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794087/running-javascript-in-selenium-using-python") 
link = driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('LinksShowcase_UrlContainer__kMj_n')")
```

The output of the javascript is stored in variable `link`
This variable `link` could be `None` in python, in case if that element still not rendered by the browser so you can code like

```
if link != None:
    print("link rendered")
else:
    print("link not rendered")
```

Comment: `if link is not None:` better then.